# logic of a line of C code

Tags: c

Could you please tell me the logic  of using `sizeof data / sizeof *data` in [this code](http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet217352.html) line 17?

```
...
unsigned char data[16];
...
size = fread(data, sizeof *data, sizeof data / sizeof *data, file);
...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a common C idiom for "number of elements in an array".

Since an array [decays to a pointer](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html#2-3) at the slightest provocation, `*data` is the first element of the array, and therefore it's dividing the total size of the array by the size of its first element, giving a count of elements.

There are any number of possible objections to this technique, whether on style grounds, the fact that it only works on variables declared as arrays (not those passed as pointer to the first element -- it relies on the decay-to-pointer not having happened yet), or possible breakage scenarios in C++ code; that said, it remains common in older C code.

Comment: Though using `*data` on something assumed to be an array makes me uneasy. I'd rather see `#define array_size(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof 0[x])` (which is a safe macro, and if you happen to use it in C++ code won't work for overloaded `[]` operators.)

Comment: Chris, shouldn't it be `sizeof x[0]`

Comment: Either way works, actually.  I think it's a holdover from assembly language register-indexing notation.

Comment: @Eimantas - `x[i]` is the same as `*(x + i)` which, due to the commutative property of addition, is the same as `*(i + x)` which is the same as `i[x]`. It's a quirk of the C language that's been around for a long time.

Comment: Writing `0[x]` instead of `x[0]` "so that it won't trip up on overloaded C++ operators" is horrible reasoning. In C++, we don't use a macro for this at all; we use a template function accepting an array by reference.

Comment: @Karl: I think the reason for that specific use of `0[x]` is for preprocessor-macro safety in plain C.  The square brackets double as parenthesis for `x` in case it expands to an expression, preventing precedence lossage.  `(x)[0]` may be less confusing, though.

Answer (score 2):

It divides the total size of the array by the size of the type of each element.
It returns the number of elements in the array

Answer (score 0):

It gives you the number of elements in the array. Because it's a compile-time value and not a run-time value, it doesn't actually evaluate anything inside the `sizeof()`, which is nice because it works even if any pointers are null or out of bounds.

(Fun facts: i the Windows C runtime, there's already a `_countof()` macro that does exactly that, and in the Windows SDK, there's the `ARRAYSIZE()` macro that also does the same thing.)

Answer (score 0):

It's simply computing the number of elements in an array -- I.e., the size of the whole array divided by the size of the first element in the array gives the number of elements (all elements in an array are the same size).